# Как сделать интернет-радио (streaming to server) на C#

Tags: c#, radio, icecast, broadcasting

Доброго времени суток.
Я хотел сделать радио, для вещания в локальной сети. Я искал как как передать поток на сервер **icecast**. Но так ничего и не нашёл, может есть и попроще способы. 
Не так уж важен сам способ, главное чтобы любой плеер мог подключиться и слушать.
Подскажите как можно организовать подобное ?

Comment: На гит хабе пример посмотреть можно https://github.com/jackpoz/OnlineRadio

Comment: Это не то. это просто плеер онлайн радио. А мне нужно самому сделать радио.

Comment: По-моему, по [этой](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/make-radio-station-at-your-home-over-internet1) ссылке то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет. не совсем. Я хотел бы сделать передачу без использования сторонних программ типа edcast или winamp. Я хотел как раз написать свой клиент для передачи аудиопотока в icecast